# LWC to display tables using picklist values

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

[image]I am trying implement a table with picklist values. I have two picklists - Items and Itemsheet.
Items - Utility, Cooking, Misc
Itemsheet - Utility (Electricity, Water, Garbage, Internet)
Cooking ( Dishwasher, Hood, Range)
Misc ( landscaping, games, maintainence)
They are both multiselect picklist. In a flow , I am calling an LWC which will display all the picklist values in table format with checkbox next to all values in the itemsheet.

Question1 : Is it possible to do this if I use multiselect picklist option? If not which data type should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this in a flow without any LWC.

But if you want to go ahead with LWC, you can either use simple input checkbox or a [lightning:dualListbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example) lists in LWC. The dual list box will take up more space so you should use checkbox.

You can have a look at these tutorials:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HPBYZRIlazk

https://automationchampion.com/tag/multi-select-checkbox/

Comment: I am pretty new to flows. Can you please let me know how to do this with flows?

Comment: Added 2 links for Multi select and checkboxes. Salesforce trailheads would be the best place to start.